# Async Task Memory Cleanup

Tags: android, android-asynctask, audiorecord

I am having a bit of trouble with how to cleanup the memory used in my `AsyncTask` when the user forces the application to quit or go to the background.

Specifically, I have an app that is using an `AsyncTask` to record audio data and graph the signal in realtime.  For the recording I am using the `AudioRecord` class, which requires you to start a recording, and then stop and release the recording object.  My problem is that I do not know how to stop and release this object.

Options I have thought about and tried:

1. Stopping the releasing the object in the `onPause`, `onStop`, and `onDestroy` methods, but this causes an exception.
2. Stopping and releasing the object in the `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask`.  The problem with this is I am not sure if this method is ever called when the user force quits the app, since the `doInBackground` method is never finished.  I have not been able to find any documentation concerning this.

My `AsyncTask` looks as follows:

```
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> drawer = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            recorder.startRecording();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            while(true) {
                int nRead = 0;
                int offset = 0;

                while(nRead != readSize) {
                    nRead += recorder.read(buffer, offset + nRead, readSize - nRead);
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
                    data[i] = buffer[i];    
                }

                publishProgress();
            }               
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... arg0) {
            view.setData(data);
            view.invalidate();
        }
    };
```

The code works great, I am just unsure the best way to make sure I properly clean up the recording object and don't leak at all.  My confusion is just as to what happens to an `AsyncTask` when the UI Thread is paused or stops, and additionally, if you are able to stop an `AudioRecord` Object from a different Thread you stared it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,

Comment: **"the user force quits the app"** - How do you define "force quits"?

Comment: Simply pressing the back or home button, sorry for not being precise in defining that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnPostExecute` will not be called because you never finish your background loop.  You need to have a condition on which you exit your loop.  You can have a variable you set in the UI and then check in the background task, or use the ability to cancel `AsyncTask`.

For example, in your `onPause()` method, you can cancel the task with `drawer.cancel(true);`

Then, in your `doInBackground` loop, check to see if the task has been cancelled.

```
if (isCancelled()) {
   // clean up here
   break;
} else {
  publishProgress();
}
```

This works as long as you do not need to touch the UI for clean up. If you need to do UI clean up, then you can override the `onCancelled` method.

Note, for long running tasks, it is recommended that you do not use `AsyncTask`. So you may want to look into using threads. From `AsyncTask` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html),

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
>   time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
>   the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
>   and FutureTask.

Comment: Ok that looks great, I had tried implementing basically the same thing on my own, but I wasn't sure that the AsyncTask would successfully finish up before super.OnPause, or super.OnStop finished.  Thank you I will try this.

Comment: Since the `AsyncTask` is in a different thread, it is not governed by the `Activity` lifecycle.  Thus, it is incumbent on the programmer to notify it (like using cancel here) if needed.

Comment: I did read that AsyncTasks are for short tasks, so I tried just launching a separate thread.  My problem with this is that the other thread is not allowed to touch the view created by my UI Thread.  I need it to be able to touch this so I can call view.invalidate to redraw the view.  But the thread from the AsyncTask can touch the view.  Any suggestions for a better design to handle this so I avoid AsyncTasks?